# Is there a way to Undo a page reload

Tags: browser

You can unto a closed tab, or go back to the previous page (undoing page view.. in a way) but

Is there a way to undo a page reload?

(any browser, any addon)

Comment: Nope.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Okay, well ***maybe*** it could be technically possible, but not in any realistic way*. There are some theoretically ways that you might be able to do it, but it would be ridiculously difficult and time consuming to the point that even *I* would give up and forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

Realistically, no.  Most browsers cache browser data.  If the page reloads and the browser detects its changed then the cached copy is overwritten with the new data.

I suppose you could theoretically roll back the cache to a certain date, if you had some kind of file versioning, but that would be tedious at best.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, no. Explained in the other answer why.

You can use web-cached version, if there's any. Search web for caching websites, only example that comes on my mind now is google web cache, you can try typing `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://example.com/` in address bar(put the thing you wanna search instead of example.com) and see if anything comes up. There are other web caching services online, but I'm not sure how broad are they.

EDIT: another caching service, which I found [on webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27414/how-to-use-googles-web-cache-to-view-a-page) is [WaybackMachine](http://archive.org/web/web.php), type the URL into the box and try your luck.